# Markers are not showing up?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

The following is the code I have for a map marker which is based off of [the official api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)  and for some reason when I click on the marker the info window wont open. Any ideas? am I doing something wrong?

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: "You are here! (at least within a " + position.coords.accuracy + " meter radius)"
    });

    var contentString = 'test';

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

Comment: Case maybe? `var infoWindow` and then in your event listener you have window lowercase (infowindow).

Comment: damn spelling mistakes >.>

Comment: Yeah, what he said. Also, it's a good idea to open up your browser's javascript console when things don't work. It would point out an error like this :)

Comment: there were no console errors though